# bash/ksh/scripting eval subshell quotes

Tags: bash, scripting, eval, quotes, ksh

I'm using ksh and having some trouble. Why does this code not run?

```
[root]$ CMD="ls -ltr"
[root]$ eval "W=$( $CMD )"
[root]$ ksh: ls -ltr:  not found.
[root]$ echo $W
```

But this works fine:

```
[root]$ CMD="ls -ltr"
[root]$ eval 'W=$('$CMD')'
[root]$ echo $W
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `$(...)` with a backslash to prevent it from being evaluated by the outside shell. The `$(...)` needs be preserved as is until it is handed off to the `eval`:

```
$ CMD="ls -ltr"
$ eval "W=\$( $CMD )"
$ echo $W
total 197092 srwxr-xr-x 1 root root...
```

Answer (score 1):

ksh is expanding the `$CMD` in the first example as a single positional argument whose value is "ls -ltr" (note the space is included. You want it expanded to two arguments: "ls" (the command name) and "-ltr" (the options). The later example cases this expansion because the expansion is in the script and then passed to the sub-shell.

If you were writing a C program, the first example gives you `argc = 1` with `argv[0] = "ls -ltr"` and the second gives you `argc = 2` with `argv[0] = "ls"` and `argv[1] = "-ltr"`. (If that example helps any.)