# ClearCase command won't run in script

Tags: unix, clearcase, ksh

I am trying to automate ClearCase check-ins via a ksh script.  There is a strange issue where the following command will not run while it's part of the automation script, but runs fine if I paste it into the command line.

Snippet of script:

```
for dir in `cat $DIRS`
do
    RUNCMD="cleartool find <<vob_directory>>/$dir -type f -exec 'cleartool co -nc \$CLEARCASE_PN'"
    print $RUNCMD
    $RUNCMD
done
exit 1
```

produces the following command

```
cleartool find <<vob_directory>> -type f -exec 'cleartool co -nc $CLEARCASE_PN'
```

Here's the error

```
cleartool: Error: Extra arguments: "co"
Usage: find { pname ... [-depth | -nrecurse | -directory]
        | [pname ...] -all [-visible | -nvisible]
        | -avobs [-visible | -nvisible]
        }
        [-name 'pattern']
        [-cview]
        [-user login-name]
        [-group group-name]
        [-type {f|d|l}...]
        [-follow]
        [-kind object-kind]
        [-nxname]
        [-element query]
        [-branch query]
        [-version query]
        {-print | -exec command-invocation | -ok command-invocation} ...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ksh` though (my first tests were in `bash`), the [`eval` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16070962/6309) you recommend is more usual ([`bash eval` is a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14687868/6309)).

You can see it in this [clearcase multisite script](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC52682).
If you need to store the result in a variable for processing, you can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760797/6309):

```
for dir in `cat $DIRS`
do
    RUNCMD="cleartool find <<vob_directory>>/$dir -type f -exec 'cleartool co -nc \$CLEARCASE_PN'"
    print $RUNCMD
    eval "res=\$( $RUNCMD )"
    print $res
done
exit 1
```

---

Original answer:

You might want to add [some quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429183/clearcase-xpn-not-parsed-as-variable-in-clearcase-command/11429466#11429466) in order to prevent the shell to expand your command too soon, as in [this example](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014227571):

```
RUNCMD="cleartool find <<vob_directory>>/$dir -type f -exec "'cleartool co -nc \$CLEARCASE_PN'""
```

or even chaging the single quote by a double quote (as in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013985730))

```
RUNCMD="cleartool find <<vob_directory>>/$dir -type f -exec "cleartool co -nc \"\$CLEARCASE_PN\""
```

(note the '`\"`' around `\$CLEARCASE_PN` in order to take into account path names with space in them)

Comment: I think you're onto something about the command being expanded (or *not* expanded) correctly.  I tried several "styles" of quotes arrangements, but ultimately none really worked. Appreciate you lending a set of eyes on this.

Comment: thanks for the links - I'm marking your reply as answer since it'll be more useful. And I don't know about the differences between `ksh` and `bash` myself.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to why this works, but a co-worker tipped me off about `eval`.  Turns out this works.

```
for dir in `cat $DIRS`
do
    RUNCMD="cleartool find <<vob_directory>>/$dir -type f -exec 'cleartool co -nc \$CLEARCASE_PN'"
    print $RUNCMD
    eval $RUNCMD
done
exit 1
```

Comment: Excellent. +1. I have referenced it in my question, with an additional reference to other ksh eval questions.